# Adding text to custom round button in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button, text

I have a custom round button in tkinter

Here is the code:

```
class RoundedButton(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, bg, width,  height = None,  command=None, color = "red", padding = 0, cornerradius = None):
        height = width if height == None else height
        cornerradius = min(width, height) / 2 if cornerradius == None else cornerradius

        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, parent, borderwidth=0, 
            relief="flat", highlightthickness=0, bg=bg)
        self.command = command

        if cornerradius > 0.5*width:
            print("Error: cornerradius is greater than width.")
            return None

        if cornerradius > 0.5*height:
            print("Error: cornerradius is greater than height.")
            return None

        rad = 2*cornerradius
        def shape():
            self.create_polygon((padding,height-cornerradius-padding,padding,cornerradius+padding,padding+cornerradius,padding,width-padding-cornerradius,padding,width-padding,cornerradius+padding,width-padding,height-cornerradius-padding,width-padding-cornerradius,height-padding,padding+cornerradius,height-padding), fill=color, outline=color)
            self.create_arc((padding,padding+rad,padding+rad,padding), start=90, extent=90, fill=color, outline=color)
            self.create_arc((width-padding-rad,padding,width-padding,padding+rad), start=0, extent=90, fill=color, outline=color)
            self.create_arc((width-padding,height-rad-padding,width-padding-rad,height-padding), start=270, extent=90, fill=color, outline=color)
            self.create_arc((padding,height-padding-rad,padding+rad,height-padding), start=180, extent=90, fill=color, outline=color)

        id = shape()
        (x0,y0,x1,y1)  = self.bbox("all")
        width = (x1-x0)
        height = (y1-y0)
        self.configure(width=width, height=height)
        self.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self._on_press)
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self._on_release)

    def _on_press(self, event):
        # print(event)
        self.configure(relief="sunken")

    def _on_release(self, event):
        # print(event)
        self.configure(relief="raised")
        if self.command is not None:
            self.command()
```

This code works but it doesn't have the functionality to add text to it. I think that to add text to this Rounded Button I would need to create another function in the class which would take the x and y coordinates and place it in it's parent, However while placing we would need to create some label or some text that would be placed according to the x and y coordinates. However, I don't know how can I calculate the position of the text that should be placed. Can someone help me out here. I am sure there must be some calculation that can be done to find the position of the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put the text at the center of canvas using `.create_text(...)`:

```py
def __init__(self, parent, bg, width, height=None, text="", font=None, command=None, color="red", padding=0, cornerradius=None):
    ...
    height = (x1-x0)
    width = (y1-y0)
    # show the text at the center of canvas
    self.create_text(width/2, height/2, text=text, font=font)
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

While @acw1668 will work I suggest you bind `configure` event to an event handler and readjust the position. In this way, the text will always stay at the center

```
class RoundedButton(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, bg, text='Hello', width=10,  height = 10,  command=None, color = "red", padding = 0, cornerradius = 4):
        super().__init__(parent)
    
        ....
        self.btn_text = self.create_text(0, 0, text=text)
        self.bind('<Configure>', self.readjust) 
        ....
    
    def readjust(self, event):
        self.coords(self.btn_text, event.width/2, event.height/2)
```